# An ideal which is zero when squared

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $I^2=0$ implies $I=0$ for $I \triangleleft R$, $R$ a ring (not necessarily with identity).

I want to prove that assuming this condition, the condition also holds for one sided ideals $I\triangleleft_{left} R$.

By way of contradiction, let $I^2=0$ for a left ideal $I$, supposing that $\exists{a}\neq0, a\in{I}$.

How do I obtain from $a$ an ideal of $R$ to apply my hypothesis?

Comment: Do you mean *the same ideal $\,I\,$ ? But then the first line is a double sided ideal but the second one part isn't?

Comment: For the second part is a left ideal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $I$ is a left ideal, then the set of finite sums $\{\sum a_ir_i\mid a_i\in I, r_i\in R\}=IR$ is an ideal of $R$. If $I$ is nonzero, so is $IR$. Look at $(IR)^2$.

---

Added to address the poscripted condition that $R$ does not necessarily have 1:

If your ring lacks unity, $IR+I=J$ is still an ideal of $R$! Look at $J^2$.

Comment: I forgot to say that $1 \notin R$ so I cannot say $IR \neq 0$

Comment: @Robert OK, thanks for letting me know. The same solution still works, though! :)

Comment: @rscgwieb when I compute $J^2=(IR+I)^2=IRIR+IRI$. If my ring is not neccesarily commutative, how do I realize that $J^2=0$?

Comment: @Robert You didn't use the fact that $I$ is a left ideal: $RI=I$.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake! Clearly, $RJ=J$, but when I compute $JR=IR+IR$ why does it coincide with J? Much Thanks

Comment: @Robert $JR=IR+IR\subseteq IR\subseteq IR+I= J$.

Comment: Thanks. Many times, I don't see the most obvious facts.